# Copying Ascii Value to int

Tags: c, ascii

I have code snippet as Below

```
unsigned char p = 0;
unsigned char t[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};     
unsigned int m = 0;
for(p=0;p<4;p++)
{
m |= t[p];
printf("%c",m);
m = m << 2;
}
```

Can anybody help me in solving this. consider i have an ascii value `abcd` stored in an array `t[]`. I want to store the same value in `'m'`. `m` is my unsigned int variable . which stores the major number. when i copy the array into `m` & print `m` . m should print `abcd`. can anybody state their logic.

Comment: @OP Note: On some platforms `sizeof(int)` may not be 4.  Maybe more, maybe less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand you, you want to encode the 4 characters into a single int.

Your bit shifting is not correct. You need to shift by 8 bits rather than 2. You also need to perform the shifting before the bitwise or. Otherwise you shift too far.

And it makes more sense, in my view, to print the character rather than `m`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const unsigned char t[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};     
    unsigned int m = 0;
    for(int p=0;p<4;p++)
    {
        m = (m << 8) | t[p];
        printf("%c", t[p]);
    }
    printf("\n%x", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, and also not use "%c" to print it out if you want it to print "abcd" at the end.

Comment: When I commented you had not included your code snippet. The original question says `printf("%c", m);` which is what I was referring to.

Comment: @Vicky Actually even that results in the desired output because %c truncates m

Comment: The way you wrote your code, `m` is really not used for printing at all, you are just printing `t` one character at a time.

Comment: @Douglas Indeed. m is an int that encodes the 4 characters. That's the whole idea.

Comment: hi David Heffernan !! why cant i print the printf("%c", m);.. when i print it with format specifier %d it shows value else it shows the last character copied.

Comment: David Heffernan !! How can i cinfirm my data is copied .. successfully. can u help me in this by giving some confirmation that the data is copied successfully

Comment: @user %c prints a single character. Use %u to print an unsigned int.

Comment: but how to confirm the data copied is successfull

Comment: Perhaps use %x to see the hex

Comment: m,m >> 4,m >> 8,m >> 12,m >> 16,m >> 20,m >> 24,m >> 28 .. i did this.. but i get some wrong answers

Comment: please be there.. i am sending you some ascii value and its equivalent hex code.. let me know if its correct

Comment: @user Part of our problem is that you did not specify what you actually want to do and so we had to guess. Print with %x for hex and that should do the job.

Comment: Asccii = 00004EB9C and Hex  = 45423943 .. is it correct

Comment: The first value you quote is hex, the second decimal. Take my exact program and run it. What is the output?

Comment: http://www.asciitohex.com/ this has helped ... one ascii character.. 1 byte... David >> thanks very Much... concept is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just look at the `t` array as an `unsigned int`?:

```
  unsigned int m = *(unsigned int*)t;
```

Or you could use an union for nice access to the same memory block in two different ways, which I think is better than shifting bits manually.

Below is an union example. With unions, both the `t` `char` array and the `unsigned int` are stored in the same memory blob. You get a nice interface to each, and it lets the compiler do the bit shifting (more portable, I guess):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
  unsigned char t[4];
  unsigned int m;
} blob;


int main()
{
  blob b;
  b.t[0]='a';
  b.t[1]='b';
  b.t[2]='c';
  b.t[3]='d';
  unsigned int m=b.m; /* m holds the value of blob b */
  printf("%u\n",m);   /* this is the t array looked at as if it were an unsignd int */
  unsigned int n=m;   /* copy the unsigned int to another one  */
  blob c;             
  c.m=n;              /* copy that to a different blob */ 
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("%c\n",c.t[i]);   /* even after copying it as an int, you can still look at it as a char array, if you put it into the blob union -- no manual bit manipulation*/

  printf("%lu\n", sizeof(c));   /* the blob has the bytesize of an int */
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign `t[p]` to `m`.

```
m = t[p];
```

this will implicitly promote `char` to `unsigned int`.

```
unsigned char p = 0;
unsigned char t[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};     
unsigned int m = 0;
for(p=0;p<4;p++)
{
    m = t[p];
    printf("%c",m);
}
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think you missed the point. The question is vague mind you. I think he wants to encode 4 chars in a single int.